Post-doc vs Research Fellow on CV after Phd thesis submission
I submitted my PhD thesis in February, and now I'm a research fellow for 1 year at an Italian university. I will defend my PhD thesis in summer. In the meantime, I'd like to apply for some jobs so I'm updating my CV. What should I select as current position, postdoc or research fellow? I don't have a PhD since I have not defended already, but I'm not sure to be a research fellow since I have only a 1-year contract.

A post-doc is a paid position. It doesn't just mean that you have finished your doctorate.

You definitely can't call yourself a postdoc if you are not yet a doc. "Doctoral researcher" is one option.

Unless you have been hired as a post-doc, that would be inappropriate. It is a paid position with a contract.
Ask your institution if you can still represent yourself as a research fellow after it expires. And, you can use it prior to its expiration, of course.
But, in any case, you can add that you are a "former" research fellow, giving dates. Your "current position" after graduation might just be "none". But since a CV is a personal document you don't need to say that. People will understand.
